# sympy nonlinsolve clear symbols from non linear equations set

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

I'm trying to clear as many symbols as possible from this set of equations with nonlinsolve:

```
a = Symbol('a', complex=True)
b = Symbol('b', complex=True)
c = Symbol('c', complex=True)
d = Symbol('d', complex=True)
b0 = Symbol('b0')
b1 = Symbol('b1')
b2 = Symbol('b2')
b3 = Symbol('b3')
b4 = Symbol('b4')
b5 = Symbol('b5')

eq1= 2 * re(a * conjugate(b) + c * conjugate(d) ) -b0
eq2 = 2 * im(b * conjugate(a) + d * conjugate(c)) - b1
eq3 = re((a * conjugate(a) + c * conjugate(c)) -(b * conjugate(b) + d * conjugate(d))) - b2
eq4 = 2 * re(a * conjugate(c) + b * conjugate(d)) - b3
eq5 =  2 * im(c * conjugate(a) + d * conjugate(b))- b4
eq6 = re((a * conjugate(a) + b * conjugate(b)) - (c * conjugate(c) + d * conjugate(d)))-b5

eqs =[j for i in [eq1 , eq2, eq3,eq4 , eq5, eq6]
  for j in i.expand(complex=True).as_real_imag()]
```

That create a set of 12 equations imaginary and real with re(a) im(a),... symbols.
Then I clear(extract) as many symbols I can with:

```
def despejanonlinsolve(ecuaciones, variable):
    print("\tdespejando  con nonlinsolve...", variable)
    res = nonlinsolve(ecuaciones,(variable))
    sustito= res.args[0][0]    
    for i in range(len( ecuaciones)):    
        ecuaciones[i] = ecuaciones[i].subs({variable:sustito})
    print("\tsimplicando con simplify...")
##    for i in range(len( ecuaciones)):    
##        ecuaciones[i] = simplify(ecuaciones[i])
    return sustito
```

by calling the above function:

```
sustiREa= despejanonlinsolve(eqs, re(a))
sustiIMa= despejanonlinsolve(eqs, im(a))
```

With 3 symbols I'll be happy, but in the third one re(b), it takes more than half hour and I have to kill the thread. I've listed the 56 combinations of 3 symbols to try different orders, but nonlinsolve never return in the third symbol.

What I need is to find sustiREa, sustiIMa... so when I go to brute force in numba I just have 6 loops instead of 8 for finding a near state vector for a given bloch for 2 qubits.

So what I can do? Is there a better way to clear symbols from a set of non linear equations?.

Answer (score 0):

There are 20 `re` and `im` "symbols" and your system is linear in 12 of them. If you are only seeking the solutions for the non-subscripted ones, the usual suggestion for an algebraic system is to try compute the Groebner basis for the equations:

```py
from sympy import groebner
v = [re(i) for i in (a,b,c,d)] + [im(i) for i in (a,b,c,d)]
groebner(eqs, v)
# GroebnerBasis([1], re(a), re(b), re(c), re(d), im(a), im(b), im(c), im(d), domain='EX', order='lex')
```

I think that means that the system has no solution. Otherwise you would have obtained a series of equations in specified symbols from which the solutions could be found, e.g.

```py
>>> var('q w');groebner((q+w-3,q-w),(q,w))
GroebnerBasis([2*q - 3, 2*w - 3], q, w, domain='ZZ', order='lex')
```

From that you can see that `q = 3/2` and `w = 3/2`.

Comment: The system does have solutions but you need to include all unknowns when constructing a Groebner basis.

Comment: I've tried first putting B0...B5  as symbols, and a second attempt with them as values, and GroebnerBasis never returns, like nonlinsolve.